# Output video has blue skin tone despite the input video being normal

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, face-detection

I am using Python and OpenCV to add glasses to a person's face in a video. I am detecting the face and nose position using Haar cascades and then pasting a transparent PNG image of the glasses onto the video using the PIL library. However, in the output video, the person's skin color appears to be blue. The input video does not have any tint and the glasses have transparent backgrounds. How can I fix this issue and make the person's skin color appear normal in the output video?

Python Code:

```
from rembg import remove
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, StringVar, OptionMenu
import tkinter.filedialog
from threading import Thread
from moviepy.editor import *

app = Tk()
app.title("Glasses Video")

header = Label(app, text="Glasses Video", font=("arial",15))
header.pack(pady=5)

Var = StringVar(app)
Var.set("Sunglasses")

Menu = OptionMenu(app, Var, "Sunglasses", "Glasses")
Menu.pack(pady=10)

vidfile = ""

def choosefile():
    global vidfile
    ask = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    vidfile = ask
    outfile.config(text=vidfile)
    
choosebtn = Button(app, text="Choose Video File", command=choosefile)
choosebtn.pack(pady=5)

outfile = Label(app, text="")
outfile.pack(pady=5)

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml")

def action():
    def t():
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidfile)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        h, w, _ = frame.shape
        clips = []
        while (cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                frame_array = np.array(frame)
                pil_image = Image.fromarray(frame_array)
                img = np.array(pil_image)
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
                eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml")
                im = pil_image.convert("RGBA")
                faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 4)
                for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
                    if len(eyes) >= 2:
                        eye_center = [(x+ex+ew//2, y+ey+eh//2) for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes]
                        nose_pos = ((eye_center[0][0]+eye_center[1][0])//2, (eye_center[0][1]+eye_center[1][1])//2)
                        if Var.get() == "Sunglasses":
                            glasses_img = Image.open("sunglasses.png").convert("RGBA")
                            glasses_scale = w / glasses_img.width
                            glasses_resized = glasses_img.resize((round(glasses_scale * glasses_img.width),round(glasses_scale * glasses_img.height)))
                            glasses_pos = (nose_pos[0]-glasses_resized.width//2, nose_pos[1]-glasses_resized.height//2)
                            im.paste(glasses_resized, glasses_pos, mask=glasses_resized)
                        else:
                            glasses_img = Image.open("glasses.png").convert("RGBA")
                            glasses_scale = w / glasses_img.width
                            glasses_resized = glasses_img.resize((round(glasses_scale * glasses_img.width),round(glasses_scale * glasses_img.height)))
                            glasses_pos = (nose_pos[0]-glasses_resized.width//2, nose_pos[1]-glasses_resized.height//2)
                            im.paste(glasses_resized, glasses_pos, mask=glasses_resized)
                frame = np.array(im.convert("RGB"))
                img = ImageClip(frame, duration=0.033)
                clips.append(img)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
            else:
                break
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        result = concatenate_videoclips(clips)
        result.audio = VideoFileClip(vidfile).audio
        result.write_videofile(os.environ['USERPROFILE']+"\\Downloads\\GlassesVideo.mp4", fps=60)
        os.system(os.environ['USERPROFILE']+"\\Downloads\\GlassesVideo.mp4")
    th = Thread(target=t)
    th.start()
    
btn = Button(app, text="Add Glasses", command=action)
btn.pack(pady=5)
    
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: opencv uses BGR channel arrangement and PIL use RGB.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you called the `PIL.Image.fromarray()` on a BGR image returned by OpenCV. Because PIL does not support the BGR format, you should convert an image to the RGB format like this.

```
            ...
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                pil_image = Image.fromarray(frame_rgb)
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                ...
            ...
```

Also note that you don't need to create deep copies of images, the `frame_array` and `img`.